# Android/SQLite right way to open/close db?

Tags: android, sqlite

Im a bit new to OOP so i want to know if im doing things correctly. For communication with database i have created a class SQLiteHelper witch does all the usual stuff (onCreate, onUpdate) and also opens and closes connection.

Here is the class, at the moment it has just on table but more will be added:

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notebook";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public static final String TABLE_LIST = "list";
    public static final String TABLE_LIST_ID = "_id";
    public static final String TABLE_LIST_NAME = "name";

    public SQLiteDatabase db;

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_LIST + "(" + TABLE_LIST_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + TABLE_LIST_NAME
                + " text not null);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LIST);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void open(){
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
        db.close();
    }
}
```

And next for each table i will create a new class witch extends previous class andd where i do all the operations relevant to that specific table.
For example ListSQL:

```
public class ListSQL extends SQLiteHelper {

    public ListSQL(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void delete(int id) {
        open();
        db.delete(TABLE_LIST, TABLE_LIST_ID + " = " + id, null);
        close();
    }

}
```

My question is that in OOP is this the correct way of doing things? Espesially the usage of open/close methods and db and TABLE variables in ListSQL seem kind of strange to me?

Answer (score 3):

I always open the db connection in `onResume()` and close it in `onPause()`. In this way database is always open for each activity.

The reason I am not doing it in `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` is once user go to other activity `onCreate()` of `new activity` will be called first then `onDestroy()` of old activity so if I perform any operation(ex:- search in my list or changing the status of user etc) on places other then `onCreate()` it will crash the app with reason **`database already closed`**.

**Note: You have to open and close the connection, even if you are using SQLiteHelper class.**

Comment: opening and close db in onResume and onPause is dangerous. Consider a query is being running while the activity goes to Paused state!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android manual, you do not need to close a database when using an SQLiteOpenHelper. The system will do it for you.

Comment: It's OK. Simply call getWritableDatabase() before every database access. Andoid will take care of everything else.

Comment: Please link to where what your answer says is stated is stated.

Comment: Take a look at the Android documentation. SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(). It says "Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database".

Comment: I think, "when you no longer need the database" occur when the android application terminated, so we do not need to close it. As long as the Android application is running, it may need the database

Answer (score -3):

As @Dan mentioned above, you do no need to open and close the database every time you do a read/write operation if you are using **SQLiteOpenHelper**. The best way to use the database is :

#### 1.

Declare and initialize an instance of **SQLiteHelper** in your [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) base class like this :

```
public class App extends Application {
  public static SQLiteHelper db;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    db = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
    db.open();

  }
}
```

#### 2.

In you activity, or any other place you want to use the DB, initialize the SQLiteHelper object like this :

```
SQLiteHelper db = App.db;
```

And then you can use the database anyway you want without having to worry about opening and closing it (:

Comment: **This is not true.** The SQLiteOpenHelper docs say __"Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database."__. If you never close the database in most cases it will seem to work. But in some cases the DB will become corrupted, **and you will lose all the data**!

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought too. But when I tried this in my app, which happens to be heavily database dependent, it worked correctly. And now it running perfectly for 250+ users, all of which are using tablets running 4.0.4 and above. I guess thats more convincing to me than the API dox :)

Comment: With only a few hundred users you may get lucky and never lose a database. Keep your fingers crossed ;-). I have an app with 118K active installs, and I wasn't closing the DB. Every couple of months a user would lose their data. Now I open/close the database!

Comment: I was running a time sensitive app and GC_CONCURRENT get getting ran every now and then which was messing with timing and I couldn't figure out until I did some heavy debugging with DDMS. I never used close and went between activities that did different read/write ops and this is what I found in my DDMS logs: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/some_app/databases/some_database' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.